# How to reload session in webdriverio combined with appium, flutter, browserstack, ios and cucumber

Tags: flutter, cucumber, appium, webdriver-io, browserstack

Im trying to reload my driver session in browserstack during the execution of a feature file.
I want to achieve this because I'm testing some login scenarios and it would be helpful if each scenario could start fresh.

I've tried multiple solutions which ill mention below, but none of them worked.

```
//app starts but cannot interact with device
//[0-0] 2023-11-07T10:37:33.182Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
Original error: {}
async function fullResetOnIos(){
    await driver.switchContext('NATIVE_APP');
    await driver.terminateApp('nl.abp.app');
    await driver.removeApp('nl.abp.app');
    await driver.installApp(appIos); // 'browserstack.midSessionInstallApps' required
    await driver.launchApp(); //deprecated in logs
    await driver.switchContext('FLUTTER');
}
```

```
// app starts but cannot interact with device
/[0-0] 2023-10-31T08:35:25.289Z DEBUG webdriver: request failed due to status 13
//[0-0] 2023-10-31T08:35:25.290Z WARN webdriver: Request failed with status 200 due to unknown error
// [0-0] 2023-10-31T08:35:08.060Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 200 due to WebDriver Error: unknown error
async function closeAndLaunchApp() {
    await driver.switchContext('NATIVE_APP');
    await driver.closeApp();
    await driver.launchApp();
    await driver.switchContext('FLUTTER');
}
```

```
// Very inconsistent, sometimes test execution is green, sometimes not because of timeouts
// When a test fails in a scenario, the last scenario will also fail in browserstack
async function reloadSession() {
    await driver.reloadSession();
}
```

```
//app under test stops functioning, caches are not cleared on iOS device
async function terminateAndActivate() {
    await driver.switchContext('NATIVE_APP');
    await driver.terminateApp('nl.abp.app');
    await driver.activateApp('nl.abp.app');
    await driver.switchContext('FLUTTER');
}
```

And many more options I've tried. Has someone faced this issue before and is able to give a solution?

Comment: if you want each scenario could start fresh. Then you will have to run different sessions only it is not possible within one test session on Browserstack

Comment: @HomeLander what do you mean it is not possible? Why not?

Comment: Hey please raise a support ticket with Browserstack → support@browserstack.com